# Abort WCF server task if client is disconnected

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, wcf-client, thread-abort

We have a WCF service hosted under Windows service. The client of this service has set up closeTimeout, receiveTimeout, openTimeout, sentTimeout set to 5 minutes. Service also has the same. In certain circumstances, WCF service may take more than 5 minutes to process a task. In this case, client aborts the call, but service process keeps on running until it finishes its job.

Now, the question is... is there any configuration/technique available which would detect that client has disconnected or timedout (or something else?) so that WCF service can just abort its tasks?

Answer (score 1):

[It's](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/286012/provide-way-to-detect-client-abort-on-iis-hosted-wcf) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427926/detecting-client-death-in-wcf-duplex-contracts) [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338842/detect-socket-disconnect-in-wcf), if not [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427926/detecting-client-death-in-wcf-duplex-contracts) (so this is pretty much a duplicate question).

Do you really want the operation to be cancelled when the client disconnects? Otherwise you could implement some state-like mechanism, using some sort of work queue.

A clients then calls `QueueQuery(query)`, which does nothing more than that and returns an identifier to the just queued query. After that, the client can keep polling `QueryStatus(id)` to retreive the status (e.g. "Queued", "Running", "Finished"), and when a query has finished, it can call `QueryResults(id)`.

Meanwhile another service (i.e. a Windows service, not a WCF service) keeps executing all queued queries.